# Creating a Debugging Suite in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, debugging, class, client-side, server-side

I wish to create a debugger suite in ASP.net for a site I'm building. One of the main problem's I'm having is interaction between plain .cs files and .aspx.cs files. Is there a workaround with this which will allow the two to work together? Should I literally code my entire backend for an ASP site with the .aspx extension, or is all of that primarily for the frontend?